# Angular 2 i18n - Translate values of ngModel

Tags: angular, internationalization

We have setup i18n with Angular 2.

We are receiving data from service. If service does not return any data then we set default value for name
data.name = "New"
If services returns data then no translation is needed.

How can we translate data.name value "New" which is hard coded ?

Does i18n support translations in .ts ?

Comment: please include proper code

Comment: Does your service accept a parameter (e.g. the original text)? If yes, you can call it again with the "New" to return the translated value.

Comment: I also have the same problem that if service does not return any data then we set default value for name i.e data.name = 'New'. If service return data then no translation is needed.
<input  type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.name" />
How to translate "New". Any support in i18n?